# How to create a tab bar using SingleViewApplication iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am new in iOS and my requirement is to implement Tab bar.
I have 5 tab bar items and for each item there is different Screen(UIViewController).
I have a HomeViewController and remaining 4 ViewControllers.
I have to show all UIViewControllers  using tabBar item.
And I have to show tab bar in bottom for all UIViewControllers.

In Image You can see.

In Image, I am in HomeViewController and for each tab I have to go for respective ViewControllers but tab bar should be present for all ViewControllers.
StoryBoard :- [image]
 I read tutorials but still confused.
How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Add what you have done so far. Where exactly you're confused? What portion of tutorials did you not understand?

Comment: There are many ways to implement tabBar, you can use your own custom tabbar instead of default TabBar. It is nothing matter that you are using single view or other.....

Comment: I already Implemented.
I took a view controller and drag a tab bar.
Now what to do?

Comment: @GouravJoshi Please tell me any good link? Thanks

Comment: @kishor0011 Show your stroryboard screen shot, it will give us idea what you have try.

Comment: That is only screen shot.
Actually Simply I took tab bar item from storyboard and drag it in HomeViewController

Answer (score 0):

You can create the class of tab view controller like this

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 254/255.0, green: 105/255.0, blue: 51/255.0, alpha: 100.0)

    for i in 0 ..< self.tabBar.items!.count {

        switch i {

        case 0:

            tabBar.items?[0].title = "Home"
            let firstTab = self.tabBar.items![i] as UITabBarItem
            learnTab.image = UIImage(named: "Homedeselected")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
            firstTab.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "Homedeselected")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
            firstTab.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-1, 0, 1, 0)
            firstTab.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0, -4)


        case 1:

            tabBar.items?[1].title = "Request"
            let secondTab = self.tabBar.items![i] as UITabBarItem
            secondTab.image = UIImage(named: "RequestDeselected")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
            secondTab.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "Requestselected")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
            secondTab.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-1, 0, 1, 0)
            secondTab.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0, -4)

        case 2:

            tabBar.items?[2].title = "Renew"
            let thirdTab = self.tabBar.items![i] as UITabBarItem
             thirdTab.image = UIImage(named: "RenewDeSelected")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
            thirdTab.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "RenewSelected")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
            thirdTab.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-1, 0, 1, 0)
            thirdTab.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0, -4)

        case 3:

            tabBar.items?[3].title = "ReSell"
            let forthTab = self.tabBar.items![i] as UITabBarItem
            forthTab.image = UIImage(named: "ReSellDeSelected")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
            forthTab.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "ReSellSelected")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
            forthTab.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-1, 0, 1, 0)
            forthTab.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0, -4)

        case 4:

            tabBar.items?[4].title = "ReCycle"
            let fifthTab = self.tabBar.items![i] as UITabBarItem
            fifthTab.image = UIImage(named: "ReCycleDeSelected")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
            fifthTab.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "ReCycleSelected")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
            fifthTab.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-2, 0, 2, 0)
            fifthTab.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0, -5)

        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {

    let rootView = self.viewControllers![self.selectedIndex] as! UINavigationController
    rootView.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(ture)


    }

}
```

}

Comment: I have 5 tab bar item.
How to show it for all view controllers?
While on each item.

Comment: you have to take tab Bar Controller and add five view controller with this tab bar controller   then when we select the tab the associate viewController appear

Comment: No 
I took tab bar and drag and drop in View controller.
And now programmatically how can I approach the same?

Comment: assign this class to the your bar controller